# App with native libs distributed as AppBundle does not work but as an APK it works

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, vitamio

I have this Android app using an old video player library called [Vitamio](https://github.com/hacknife/Vitamio). Vitamio has not been updated for ages however it does work, at least until recently.

The library (and the app) works fine when compiled into an ordinary APK but if I create an App Bundle, I get a crash due to "java.lang.UnSatisfiedLinkError" when running the app on the phone.
The Google PlayConsole does not give me any errors nor warnings.
As a test, I set "enableSplit = false" for "abi" in the app build.gradle file but there was no difference.

It seems strange that when compiling to an AppBundle, it would mess up things so previous compilations as an APK do not work any longer.

Anyway, I could fix this?

Comment: There are already many posts talking about this. The APKs generated from the App Bundle leave native libraries uncompressed in the APK so they're not extracted at installation on the device, thus saving space on the device. Depending how you load the native libraries, this can lead to this exception. Ensure you use the Android standard way of loading native libraries. If you can't for any reason, then you can disable this feature using `android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false` in the gradle.properties file. At the cost of a bigger app for your users.

Comment: Thank you Pierre. I was not aware of this.
I tested it with enableUncompressedNativeLibs set to false and it worked. I will try and see if I can change the way Vitamio loads the native libs.
Unfortunately, this is not really a solution for me since I am using another development project called B4A and it does not use Gradle. Everything is compiled using a customized toolchain but hopefully, the AppBundle tool may have an option to set this value too. I will need to test.
If you wish to put what you wrote as an answer, I will gladly accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APKs generated from the App Bundle leave native libraries uncompressed in the APK so they're not extracted at installation on the device, thus saving space on the device. Depending how you load the native libraries, this can lead to this exception.

Ensure you use the Android standard way of loading native libraries. If you can't for any reason, then you can disable this feature using `android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false` in the gradle.properties file. At the cost of a bigger app for your users.

If you don't use Gradle to build the bundle, the information about the compression of native libraries is stored in the BundleConfig.pb inside the bundle (which is passed to bundletool by the build system). See https://github.com/google/bundletool/blob/master/src/main/proto/config.proto#L77